# How do I check if the content of a CSV was already uploaded to the database when duplicate records are allowed?

Tags: java, sql, csv

I have a database table where each record has an primary key ID and a series of columns that are NOT unique. Therefore having duplicate records (except for the ID) is definetely possible and accepted.

The table is populated by CSV.

What I'm wondering tho is if there's a way to validate/check if the content of the CSV was already saved in the past to the database?

I could **check if I can find records that are in the same exact order as those in the CSV file** but that sounds expensive and I'm not even sure how to implement it.

Another option would be to hash the file and store the hash somewhere after the upload, so that I can check the hash of an upload file and have an hint that this file was maybe already uploaded.

I'm open to advices on how to solve this problem and, if none, how to implement the part in bold (the has method is pretty straightforward, I think).

Thanks!

Comment: Your hash solution sounds much more elegant. It shouldn't cost much to store a list of MD5s.

Comment: Good that you agree with the hash method, but it's not a perfect solution. I'm open to proposals if you have them!

Answer (score 0):

The canonical solution to this problem is to add a `unique` index or constraint to the table, containing all the other columns.  This will prevent the duplicate rows from being inserted.

The cost of such an index should not be very large.  It is also more flexible than a hash.  For instance, a unique constraint can take collations into account -- treating lowercase and uppercase characters as the same.

Of course, you can *allow* duplicates if you like.  To just detect them, use a regular index.

The downside of an index is that it occupies additional space -- about as big as the original table.  In applications where space is an issue -- because the table is really humungous -- then hashing is an option.  However, hashes are not a 100% solution, because they have collisions:  different values with the same hash value.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Do you mind explain in more details, maybe with some code? An example that comes to my mind is a transaction list of a bank account: you could pay the same amount of money, the same day, to the same person and so on, but the id of two "identical" records is different. I know that indexes are used to to speed up searching in the database, but I'm not that familiar with them. How would you apply your solution to this problem?

Comment: @CapitanoGiovarco . . . If you care about sample data, then ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  You have asked a generic question, so this is a generic answer.

Comment: Ok then put it like that: I've read that when an unique index has multiple columns, then the combination of values in these columns is unique. However, This is not what I want. If I have for example {id=1, amount=5€, addressee=Jack} and then I try to add {id=2, amount=5€, addressee=Jack}, this insert will fail, but this isn't what I want. Did I misunderstand your comment?